# Changing masterpage on public site requires login

Tags: sharepoint-online, public-website

I created a public facing site in SharePoint Online. When I change the masterpage it is no long public facing and redirects the users to the login page.

I have made sure that it doesn't link to any restricted files..   But for some reason I cant make it public facing. I turned "make website offline" of and on (so its online)

Comment: Are you applying your custom master page or out-of-the box master page?

Comment: Is the masterpage checked in and published? Any referencing custom JavaScript or CSS files?

Comment: Did you check the site in Fiddler to understand where it is breaking or which file is causing the issue?

Answer (score 0):

After I published a major version it all worked :)

thanks